# Node.js - How to check if Unix Domain Socket exists in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, unix-socket

I am writing a docker client in Node.js. It must connect to unix domain socket `/var/run/docker.sock` if it exists or fallback to `TCP` socket, typically `tcp://localhost:2375` (when client is running on Windows).

The question is - How can I verify the presence of domain socket before falling back to `TCP` socket?

> *I can probably check for the presence of TCP socket as [mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51204960/5723098) or attempt to connect to the domain socket. But that does not look clean.*

Comment: Since it's a file, can't you just check whether the file exists with the normal file APIs?